# Trying to achieve additional scoping in C# Properties

Tags: c#

I'm working on a utility that generates lots of C# classes. Most generated classes are small, but some get up to 50+ public members. I would like to be able to add an additional level of scoping just to reduce clutter and make them more IntelliSense-friendly.

For example, say I generate a class Foo with the following members:
Apple, Banana, Cantaloupe, Dog, Elephant, Fox, Geranium, Hibiscus, Iris.
Instead of IntelliSense showing all 9 members when I type `new Foo().`, I want to be able to scope the properties to categories. For example, `new Foo().Animals.` would list Dog, Elephant, and Fox.

The only way I can think of to do this is to create an inner class for each category and creating a property on the parent class that returns an instance of the child class. This doesn't seem very elegant and I'm not sure if it's a good use of nested classes.

```cs
public class Scope
{
    public FruitProperties Fruit { get; private set; }
    public AnimalProperties Animals { get; private set; }
    public FlowerProperties Flowers { get; private set; }

    public Scope()
    {
        Fruit = new FruitProperties();
        Animals = new AnimalProperties();
        Flowers = new FlowerProperties();
    }

    public class FruitProperties
    {
        public string Apple { get { return "Apple"; } }
        public string Banana { get { return "Banana"; } }
        public string Cantaloupe { get { return "Cantaloupe"; } }
    }
    public class AnimalProperties
    {
        public string Dog { get { return "Dog"; } }
        public string Elephant { get { return "Elephant"; } }
        public string Fox { get { return "Fox"; } }
    }
    public class FlowerProperties
    {
        public string Geranium { get { return "Geranium"; } }
        public string Hibiscus { get { return "Hibiscus"; } }
        public string Iris { get { return "Iris"; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: If they are strings in real code I'd suggest you to use `enum`

Comment: Unfortunately they're not simple strings in the real code. Mostly method calls.

Comment: Well you achieve what you want with the code above... But alternativly you could make them static. Then you would not need to initialize `Scope` class.